# How to remove search box from Chosen JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

On github it says that the search box was now optional in the chosen select boxes. Does anyone know how to remove it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The current version of [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) provides two methods to control the display of the search box. Both are passed in as options during initialization. To hide the search box completely pass in the option `"disable_search": true`:

```
$("#mySelect").chosen({
  "disable_search": true
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to show the search iff there are a certain number of options, use the option `"disable_search_threshold": numberOfOptions` (where `numberOfOptions` is the minimum number of options required before showing the search box):

```
$("#mySelect").chosen({
  "disable_search_threshold": 4
});
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  // Create a set of OPTION elements from some dummy data
  var words = ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet,", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit", "duis", "ullamcorper", "diam", "sed", "lorem", "mattis", "tristique", "integer", "pharetra", "sed", "tortor"],
      options = $($.map(words, function(word) {
        return $(document.createElement('option')).text(word)[0];
      }));
  $('select').each(function() {
    // Add the dummy OPTIONs to the SELECT
    var select = $(this).append(options.clone());
    // Initialize Chosen, using the options from the
    // `data-chosen-options` attribute
    select.chosen(select.data('chosen-options'));
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em; }
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1.4em; }
  label .label {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: .2em; }
select {
  width: 14em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.5.1/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.5.1/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  <div class='label'>Default behavior</div>
  <select name='default' data-chosen-options='{}'></select>
</label>
<label>
  <div class='label'>No search at all</div>
  <select name='no-search' data-chosen-options='{ "disable_search": true }'></select>
</label>
<label>
  <div class='label'>Search iff more than 4 items</div>
  <select name='conditional-search' data-chosen-options='{ "disable_search_threshold": 4 }'></select>
</label>
<label>
  <div class='label'>Search iff more than 32 items</div>
  <select name='conditional-search' data-chosen-options='{ "disable_search_threshold": 32 }'></select>
</label>
```

Comment: I downloaded the new version and it works with disable_search: true now, thanks

Comment: Do you know where has the official reference ?

Comment: Doesn't work anymore, it's not mentioned anywhere in documentation

Comment: I've added a code example showing how these two options work. Both options are now documented on the [Chosen options](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html) page. FYI, I recommend also checking out [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) as well. Both libraries seem to be well maintained and documented right now, so it's a matter of preference and which library better fulfills your project requirements :-)

Answer (score 3):

just hide it when needed with

```
$('.chzn-search').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

chosen.jquery.js just set the style of search box `display:none` in div with class `chzn-search`

```
<div class="chzn-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="display:none;" /></div>
```

Comment: I don't want to remove it permanently. Just from certain select boxes on certain pages. For example if I have a long select box, I like the search box, but fo small select boxes, I'd rather remove it.

Comment: This HTML is generated by the Javascript and the answer provides static HTML. Additional Javascript will be necessary to modify the generated HTML.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. I do this and it works great:
`<div class="no-search"><select class="chosen"></select></div>`
and 
`$('.chosen').chosen();`
with the css `.no-search .chzn-search { display: none; }`